# Let R be a Z-graded ring. Prove that R is Noetherian if and only if R satisfies the ascending condition on homogeneous ideals.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

The problem is "Let $R$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring. Prove that $R$ is Noetherian if and only if $R$ satisfies the ascending condition on homogeneous ideals."

I know it sounds a lot like [Ascending chain conditions on homogeneous ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147466/ascending-chain-conditions-on-homogeneous-ideals). But here is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring and clearly we can't use the same technique. Help me

Comment: I suppose it's clear that ACC on homogeneous ideals implies that every homogeneous ideal is finitely generated. Then use Theorem 1.5.5.from Bruns and Herzog.