# Ascending / descending chain condition on graded modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R = \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} R_n$ be a graded commutative ring. Then $R$ is noetherian / artinian if and only if it has the ascending / descending chain condition for *homogeneous* ideals, see [Ascending chain conditions on homogeneous ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147466/ascending-chain-conditions-on-homogeneous-ideals).

Is the same also true for a graded module $M = \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} M_n$? I.e. is $M$ noetherian / artinian if and only if it has the ascending / descending chain condition for graded submodules?

I actually only want to use this if $R$ is noetherian, but I'm not sure this helps in any way.

For some context why I'm interested in this, see [Divided power algebra is artinian as a module over the polynomial ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979095/divided-power-algebra-is-artinian-as-a-module-over-the-polynomial-ring).

Comment: well, if I remember my algebra correctly, for finitely generated modules, these properties should literally just carry over. i.e. $R$ is noetherian (artinian) if and only if the analogous chain conditions hold for all finitely generated modules.

Comment: The ring is positive graded ring in the proof of.in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/147466/453628 Is this true for atbitrary graded ring

Comment: @Enkidu Yes, this is easy, because finitely generated modules are quotients of some $R^n$ and being noetherian/artinian is preserved by finite sums and quotients. But In my application, $R$ is not artinian and $M$ is not finitely generated either, see my other linked question. I would like to know if it would suffice to show the acc/dcc for *graded* submodules of $M$ only.

Comment: @Sky In my application the ring itself is positively graded, but the module is not. I don't know about the other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A $\mathbb{Z}$-graded module over an $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring is noetherian *as a graded module* if and only if it is so *as an ungraded module.*
>
> A $\mathbb{Z}$-graded module *with well-ordered support* over an $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring is artinian *as a graded module* if and only if it is so *as an ungraded module.*

This holds by Propositions 5.4.7 and 5.4.5 in C. Nastasescu, F. Van Oystaeyen, *Methods of graded rings,* Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1836, Springer, Berlin, 2004.

I do not know whether the hypothesis on the support in the second statement can be omitted, but I doubt it.